# Flexbox vertical alignment not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

Right now my div `content` is only centre-aligning horizontally, but I aim for it to align that way vertically, too. I've tested across Safari on Mac and iOS and Chrome for Android.

Here's my CSS;

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #002560;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002560, #0c182b);
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

My HTML looks like this;

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;" id="content">
    <div>
        <h1>I'd love to be centre aligned correctly.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'm seeing on iOS (and other platforms);

[image: Screenshot of my webpage.]

Comment: You have to set up the height to 100% for your div element.

Comment: @JulianEspinosa *facepalm* Thanks for picking up on that, I should know better!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could add height. And often it is easier to have all styles in the css.

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
    background: #002560;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002560, #0c182b);
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="height-100 center" id="content">
  <div>
        <h1>I'd love to be centre aligned correctly.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add `height` on `#content` div. Check updated snippet below...

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #002560;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002560, #0c182b);
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;" id="content">
    <div>
        <h1>I'd love to be centre aligned correctly.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why position absolute?

Comment: In this case, flexbox does that already. Without flexbox you might need that. You don't even need text-align: center

Comment: yes don't need position absolute and other css, specifying height is enough

Comment: @Esko without `height` you can't `vertical align` single element.

Comment: @SuperUser Yes you can, flexbox does that, test it yourself with just height: 100%;

Comment: OK, My mistake, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

**You must set height**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #002560;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002560, #0c182b);
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;height:500px;width:100%;" id="content">
    <div>
        <h1>I'd love to be centre aligned correctly.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Centering is applied using flex-container's calculated height. In this case you should set it explicitly (by default body with take content's height).

Also `body` can be your flex-container. So you can remove you extra `div` wrappers.

```css
body {
    background: #002560;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002560, #0c182b);
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    
    /* Also you can apply this for common body layout */
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>I'd love to be centre aligned correctly.</h1>
```